# Operator== overloaded does not compare

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm just writing my first objected oriented project at my univeristy. I found difficulty in overloading == operator. 
In my base class Organism I have

```
friend bool operator==(const Organism &curr, const Organism &other);
bool operator==(const Organizm &curr, const Organizm &other) {
    if (curr.x == other.x) {
        if (curr.y == other.y)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Animal inherits from Organism, Fox and Wolf inherits from Animal.
When i try to compare

```
    Fox f(1, 2);
    Wolf w( 1, 2);
    Organizm *o1, *o2;
    o1 = &f;
    o2 = &w;
    bool ok = (o1 == o2);
```

The comparision return false, even though proper variables are equal.
I need operator== for std::find, because I keep all my organisms in std::vector.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but nested `if` is equivalent to logical AND, and comparisons returns a boolean result. So all you need to do in the function body is `return curr.x == other.x && curr.y == other.y;`

Comment: Also, pay close attention. Organism and Organizm are two different words.

Comment: About that Organism and Organizm im using polish names for classes and when i translate it before posting i forget to change all

Comment: The reason you're having difficulty is because you're being forced to use Object Oriented programming in a context where it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not comparing those objects, and your operator is not even being invoked.

You are comparing *pointers* to those objects. Obviously that comparison will always fail as two objects cannot exist in the same place at the same time.

I imagine you meant to write either of the following:

```
Fox f(1, 2);
Wolf w(1, 2);

Organizm* o1 = &f;
Organizm* o2 = &w;

const bool ok = (*o1 == *o2);
```

or, better:

```
Fox f(1, 2);
Wolf w(1, 2);

const Organizm& o1 = f;
const Organizm& o2 = w;

const bool ok = (o1 == o2);
```

or, simply:

```
Fox f(1, 2);
Wolf w(1, 2);

// implicit conversions are a thing!
const bool ok = (f == w);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. My main problem is making std::find in vector work. Does my operator== work good with std::fing?

Comment: @SzymonStrzelka: Try it and find out!

Comment: I have 
 
`vector <Organizm*> organizmy;
vector <Organizm*>::iterator i = world.organisms.begin();

  o = this->newAnimal(world, this->x + _x, this->y + _y);

  i = find(world.organisms.begin(), world.organisms.end(), o);`
and it finds anything every time. Even though here is an  element with the same x and y

Comment: @SzymonStrzelka: Your vector does not contain `Organizm`s. It contains pointers. So your `std::find` operation needs to build in a dereference operation, just like your own code would do, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: So i need to 
`find(world.organisms.begin(), world.organisms.end(), *o)`?

Comment: @Szymon: No, that will not work. Your vector does not contain `Organizm`s; it contains pointers. Try a Google search for `c++ find vector pointers`, something like that. _[edit: yep, it's the first result]_

Comment: Ok, i think now im able to overcome this. Thank you!

Comment: @SzymonStrzelka: Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code does not compare objects; it compares their addresses:

```
bool ok = (o1 == o2); // Compare address of f to address of w
```

If you would like to compare objects referenced by pointers, the call should be like this:

```
bool ok = (*o1 == *o2);
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
Organizm *o1 = &f;
Organizm *o2 = &w;
bool ok = (o1 == o2);
```

Your are comparing **pointers**

you want

```
bool ok = (*o1 == *o2);
```

to compare objects using your custom operator.